# tikz-uml reduce distance between timelines

Tags: tikz-uml

I created a sequence diagram with `tikz-uml` and I would like to reduce the distance between the involved entities.

I currently have:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlseqdiag}
% Entities required for interaction
\umlactor[class=User]{user}
\umlobject[class=App]{app}
\umlobject[class=Script]{api}
\umlobject[class=Controller]{sessionCtrl}
% User creates a session
\begin{umlcall}[op=create(name), type=synchron, return=sessionView]{user}{app}
  % App posts session data to server
  \begin{umlcall}[op=create(name), type=synchron, return=sessionId]{app}{api}
    \begin{umlcall}[op=create(name), type=synchron, return=session]{api}{sessionCtrl}
    \end{umlcall}
  \end{umlcall}
  % App navigates to new session
  \begin{umlcall}[op=open(id), type=synchron, return=session]{app}{api}
  \end{umlcall}
\end{umlcall}
\end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and it creates the following the result:

[image: Result]

How can I reduce the distance between the objects to make it fit the page?

Comment: Great first question!  A warm welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2):

Been struggling with that, you can define the `x` coordinate like this:

```
\umlobject[x=12, class=Controller]{sessionCtrl}
```

Use option `x` on the object you are creating, that will do the trick!